# Optimize API call in Symfony

Tags: api, symfony, guzzle

How optimize an API call in symfony?

I call with Guzzle bundle, but the time in some situations is very long.

In client application call a function from the server. 
In server application extract the objects from the database and send back to the client.
In client creat the new object with properties from server respons.

Comment: maybe with _caching_ ?

Comment: How? I work with php and symfony for just one month, I am beginner. :D

Comment: The idea is to use Symfony API caching. There are plenty of material about it for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038462/how-to-properly-cache-my-symfony2-apis and many more! ;)

Comment: Nice, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to improve your API calls is to use caching. In Symfony there are many different ways to achieve this. I can show you one of them (`PhpFileCache` example):

In **services.yml** create cache service:

```
your_app.cache_provider:
    class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\PhpFileCache
    arguments: ["%kernel.cache_dir%/path_to/your_cache_dir", ".your.cached_file_name.php"]
```

(Remember, you need `Doctrine` extension in your app to work)

Then pass your caching service `your_app.cache_provider` to any service where you need caching:

Again in your **services.yml**:

```
some_service_of_yours:
    class: AppBundle\Services\YourService
    arguments: ['@your_app.cache_provider']
```

Finally, in your service (where you want to perform API caching):

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider;

class YourService
{
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(CacheProvider $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function makeApiRequest()
    {
        $key = 'some_unique_identifier_of_your_cache_record';

        if(!$data = $this->cache->fetch($key))
        {
            $data = $provider->makeActualApiCallHere('http://some_url');
            $this->cache->save($key, serialize($data), 10800); //10800 here is amount of seconds to store your data in cache before its invalidated, change it to your needs
        }

        return $data; // now you can use the data
    } 
}
```

This is quite GENERIC example, you should change it to your exact needs, but idea is simple. You can cache data and avoid unnecessary API calls to speed things up. Be careful though, because cache has drawback of presenting stale(obsolete) data. Some things can (and should) be cached, but some things don't.

Comment: This tweet of Julien Pauli, a maintainer of PHP, should discourage to use such caching mechanisms for HTTP: https://twitter.com/julienpauli/status/767633093138219008

Comment: @KévinDunglas, please mind comments under that tweet (which do conflict with the statement). The choice of choosing caching approach is purely up to developer depending on type of task its size etc. There is no _one and only_ true way. Instead of blindly following whatever someone says (core developer, president, pope etc.) its better to question yourself on WHY and WHEN to use certain approach.

Comment: Implementing correctly and in a secure way the HTTP protocol is hard. Designing an efficient cache system, especially optimizing memory occupation is harder, and PHP is not designed for that.

Doctrine Cache is a good piece of software, but it isn't designed nor optimized for HTTP caching (it has a lot of good other use cases).
By the way, if you really want to use PHP for HTTP caching, you should use the Symfony's builtin HttpCache reverse proxy directly.

You might be be interested by this discussion about HTTP cache in PHP: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19705

Answer (score 0):

**If you control the server**

You should put a cache reverse proxy like Varnish on top of your PHP server. The PHP app must send HTTP cache headers to tell to the proxy how many time it must cache the request. Alternatively, you can use a library like [FOSHttpCache](http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to setup a cache invalidation strategy (the PHP server will purge the cache from the proxy when an update of the data occurs - it's a more advanced and complex scenario).
The PHP server will not even be called if the requested resource is in the reverse proxy cache.

You should also use a profiler like Blackfire.io or xhprof to find why some parts of your PHP code (or your SQL queries) take so many time to be executed, then optimize.

**If you control the client**

You can use [this HTTP cache middleware for Guzzle](https://github.com/Kevinrob/guzzle-cache-middleware) to cache every API result according to HTTP headers sent by the API.